# Add a new link to Leads Home Page Tools Section

Tags: leads, home-page-component, customization

I need to add a new link (which goes to a separate VF page) to the Tools section of the Leads Home page via a Managed Package. (i.e When users install the package in their organization, it should add this link to the Leads Home). What is the best way to do this without creating a whole new Home page for the Leads tab?

[image: Screenshot]